# Changing Youtube video using Javascript when using HTML5 player

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have  a HTML5 YouTube Player on my Website:

```
<iframe id="video1" 
        width="600" 
        height="283" 
        src="youtubeurl" 
        frameborder="0" 
        allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

That renders OK. Now I want to change the video being played based on a JavaScript function call:

```
function doSomething() { ... }
```

Here is what I've tried.

```
$("#video1").attr('src', 'otherURL' + '?' + "wmode=transparen");
$('#video1').hide();
setTimeout(function () { 
  $('#video1').show(); }, 100);
```

But nothing happens! How can I do that?

Comment: is the `otherUrl` being concated as a variable, like `otherUrl + "?wmode=transparen"`? Or is it a string, like in the example you have provieded?

Comment: its the url to the youtube video

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried embedding a YouTube player into your page? If you do this it will make your life easier trying to operate on the player functionality.

Some of the embedded player functions include:

```
 loadVideoByUrl()
 playVideo()
 nextVideo()
```

You can find everything you need [here in the YouTube JavaScript API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/js_api_reference)

You can embed your player into an `iframe` using the [examples detailed here.](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference)

Comment: can you please provide me with a sample ?

Comment: I've linked some examples and edited my post. Go through them and come back if you have more questions.

Answer (score 0):

To control YouTube player you'd better use YouTube API. It is pretty easy. check out this exaple http://jsfiddle.net/uLygZ/1/ I tried to make free of jQuery calls, but note that my scripts are executed inside `document-ready` handler.

For more information see https://developers.google.com/youtube/